# Magento, all pages redirects to HTTPS

Tags: http, magento, redirect, ssl, https

A Magento site I been asked to look into lately has recently been redirecting all traffic to HTTPS.  When a link on the page points to HTTP with SEO URL's, Magento is return a HTTPS page with catalog URL's instead.

I am not sure if anyones been in and changed the SSL settings, is there anything I can check or change to return it back to normal.  How do I specify what areas of the site is HTTPS?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

i) Check Base Url in the admin console.

Admin --> System --> Configuration --> Web --> UnSecure --> BAse Url & Base Link Url

if its in https change that to http.

ii) Check your htaccess. If you are not sure whats changed. Take a back up of you htaccess and create a new htaccess. Copy htaccess.sample in your magento root folder and change the name to .htaccess

> Before these two steps make sure that you have the right configuration in your ssl.conf

Comment: thanks a lot for the tips, what should I be checking for in the ssl.conf, I am on a hosting plan, would I usually have access to this file?

Comment: The strange thing is the homepage is not redirecting to https.  I had a look at the GA data and it showing that there are still a tiny percentage of hits on non-https pages.

Comment: Triple checked unsecure and secure base urls.  Did the .htaccess swaps nothing.